# mysql sequence swapping values

Tags: mysql

Database table

```
id      serial      account     speeddialsort   dest
107     155         501         1               020341542
115     155         501         2               004407152222
116     155         501         3               00951242454
117     155         501         4               0794245544
118     266         700         1               004465652212
119     266         700         2               0044845482
```

Data presented to user

This a list of account's 501 speed dial slots.
I can send the speeddialsort and dest if required from a form, what sql method can I then use to manage user editing of the speed dial order.

The order is to be moved up or down

```
speeddialsort       dest
#1                  020341542
#2                  004407152222
#3                  00951242454
#4                  0794245544
```

For example user selects speed dial #3 be moved up. The speeddialsort of #2 and #3 will need to be swapped

Comment: An easy way is to remove the records for the account and then re-add them in the new ordering.

Answer (score 0):

I asume speeddialsort is UNIQUE and dest isn't?

Asume $int_short to be supplied sort_id and $int_previous_sort to be the value is was before:

```
INSERT INTO table (speeddialsort, dest)
SELECT speeddialsort, dest
FROM (SELECT {$int_sort} AS speeddialsort, dest
      FROM table
      WHERE speeddialsort = {$int_previous_sort}
      UNION ALL
      SELECT {$int_previous_sort}, dest
      FROM table
      WHERE speeddialsort = {$int_sort})
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dest = VALUES(dest)
```

In case both are UNIQUE, it'd be easier to simply remove and readd them. That, or:

```
INSERT INTO table (speeddialsort, dest)
SELECT speeddialsort, dest
FROM (SELECT {$int_sort} AS speeddialsort, NULL AS dest
      UNION ALL
      SELECT {$int_previous_sort}, NULL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT {$int_sort}, dest
      FROM table
      WHERE speeddialsort = {$int_previous_sort}
      UNION ALL
      SELECT {$int_previous_sort}, dest
      FROM table
      WHERE speeddialsort = {$int_sort})
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dest = VALUES(dest)
```

Should work aswell.

Answer (score 0):

**Move Up:**

```
UPDATE my_table AS t1 SET t1.dest =
    IFNULL( ( SELECT t2.dest FROM my_table AS t2 
      WHERE t2.speeddialsort IN( {$i}, {$i-1} ) AND
         t2.account = $account AND t2.dest <> t1.dest ), t1.dest )
    WHERE t1.speeddialsort IN( {$i}, {$i-1} ) AND t1.account = {$account}
```

to **Move Down** just replace `$i-1`s with `$i+1`

($i is the speeddialsort you want to move, $account is the account id)

Answer (score 0):

I create a table and the row serial is made in a continuous sequence by using 
[mysql user defined variable.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)

ID                serial

101                    1

103                    2

104                    3

110                    4

In this to move the item with serial 4 to 2

```
SET @a = 2;
UPDATE tableName SET serial = @a:=@a + 1 WHERE serial >= 2 AND serial < 4  
ORDER BY    serial DESC;
UPDATE tableName SET serial = 2 WHERE ID = 1;
```

This query will add 1 to all the serial values less than 4 and greater than 2 and then update the row with serial 4 with value 2.

And to move item 2 to 4

```
SET @b = 4;
UPDATE tableName SET ord = @b:=@b - 1 WHERE  serial > 2 AND serial < (4 + 1)  
ORDER BY serial DESC;
UPDATE tableName SET serial = 4 WHERE ID = 1 ;
```

I am not talking about [Auto Increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).In my case I need to order the values as user required.So i cannot use Auto increment.